# How to add glyphicon in input placeholder?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, placeholder, glyphicons

Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/3218/

```
<div class="right-inner-addon ">
    <input type="search"
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="&#xe003" />
</div>
```

I want the glyphicon to show up as a placeholder in the input text box. But it does not render. Where as if I had put a font awesome icon hexa code, it renders.

How to make it work in glyphicon (without introduing any new tag like span or i just for showing the icon like

```
<i class= glyphicon-search"</i>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add class `glyphicon` into it

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="right-inner-addon ">
  <input type="search" class="form-control glyphicon" placeholder="&#xe003" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To Achieve this you need to add `glyphicon glyphicon-search` class in input tag. 
For updated fiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/3219/)

```
<div class="right-inner-addon ">
    <input type="search"
       class="form-control glyphicon glyphicon-search" 
       placeholder="&#xe003" />
</div>
```